Is VelocityJS compatible with typescript?
I want to use velocityjs npm library in my typescript project for use case related to methods like lenght(), count(), etc. Is it possible to achieve this? If yes, then can some example be provided for this.
I tried importing the library in my project but didn't work.

Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.
